# How to debug elisp?

Tags: debugging, emacs, elisp

Normally the easiest way to debug is using `printf`. What can I do to debug emacs-lisp? How can I print something to emacs editor from elisp? Or *is there any way to debug elisp code?*

For example, how can I check if the following code is run in `.emacs` file?

```
(load "auctex.el" nil t t)
```

Comment: This [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Debugging.html) may be help to you.

Comment: Allow me to recommend [this blog post](http://endlessparentheses.com/debugging-emacs-lisp-part-1-earn-your-independence.html) on Edebug.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

The debugger (edebug) is pretty straight forward to use.  Go to the definition of the function, and type <kbd>M-x edebug-defun</kbd>.  The next time it is called, you'll be able to step through the code as with every other debugger.  Type <kbd>?</kbd> for the list of keybindings, or check out the documentation for [edebug](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/emacs-lisp-intro/html_node/edebug.html).

Comment: It's worth noting the most important keybindings while debugging: `SPC` to proceed to the next step, `i` for stepping in, `o` for stepping out, `q` for quitting.

Answer (score 36):

There are two debuggers in GNU Emacs:

- edebug -- explained in another post here
- debug

I use `debug`. These are common entry points (ways to use it):

- `M-x debug-on-entry` followed by a function you want to enter using the debugger.
- `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` --
  Enter the debugger when when an error is raised.
- `M-x toggle-debug-on-quit` --
  Enter the debugger when the user hits <kbd>C-g</kbd>.
- Place explicit calls to function `debug` at particular places (breakpoints) in your code, to enter the debugger at those places:

```
    (debug)
```

You step through the debugger using <kbd>d</kbd>, or <kbd>c</kbd> to skip over the details of a particular evaluation.

Comment: how to check the values of different variables? I am able to debug through a function but don't know how to check value for different variables.

Comment: @Alok: You can place the cursor over a variable and press `RET`, or press `e` and evaluate the variable you're interested in.

Comment: You can evaluate any sexp in the original (calling) context. You can also provide a sexp to evaluate to function `debug`, so it shows you the value when the debugger is opened. E.g., `(debug nil (current-buffer))`.

Comment: thanks, I came here looking to undo what happens when you `pkill -SIGUSR2 -i emacs` from a shell (it toggles debug-on-quit).  That's another way to start `debug` if emacs has hung in some function somewhere and you just want to break the loop, but `C-g` doesn't work

Comment: @Drew is there a way to 'step-over'? I mean to evaluate the current expression without the debugger increasing depth into any of the subexpressions? `d` is more of a 'step-into', and most debuggers have both. Similarly, a 'step-out' would be nice.

Comment: @nate, [Elisp docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/elisp.html#Debugger-Commands) list available commands. In particular, see `j`, `u` and `e` keybindings. `Edebug` seems to provide more fine-grained possibility to control the flow if `debug` is not enough.

Comment: @nate: That's what `c` does. I called that "skip over the details". `c` stands for "continue", presumably. It evaluates the given step completely, without making you step through every intermediate step to accomplish that.

Comment: @Y.E. Ah, ok. Thanks for the suggestions. I realized what i wanted here. If i put a (debug) at the top of a function, i can 'd' to eval the next expr (the first expr of the function). It is autoflagged to break on exit with a star. Then i hit c and it runs and i see its return value. Then i hit 'd' one more time to debug the next function in the list. It is kind of a 'd-c-d-c-d-...' combo to do the "step-over" that i intended.

Answer (score 24):

This is useful for printing values

```
(message "Hello (%s)" foo)
```

but doesn't work so well for data structures. For that, use

```
(prin1 list-foo)
```

or (prin1-to-string) to embed it in a (message).

Comment: You can use "%S" to print a data structure with format

Comment: Crucial tip for the ignorant (as I was): The output goes to the buffer `*Messages*.

Answer (score 8):

The easiest way to debug may be to run your code interactively. You can do that in a lisp buffer by placing your point after the expression and running <kbd>C-x C-e</kbd> (`eval-last-sexp`).

Alternatively:

```
(message "hello world")
```

<kbd>C-h f message</kbd> to find out more about the built in message function.  If you generate lots of messages, you may want to customize the variable `message-log-max` to a larger value.

Comment: This is the equivalent of the `printf` approach, and it is sometimes a very good one.

Answer (score 4):

To answer your questions one by one:

- print something: there's a million ways.  (message "Hello") puts the string in the echo area; (insert "hello") puts the string into the current buffer at point ...
- how can I check if the following code is run: I'd just replace "auctex.el" with (say) "frotzumotzulous" (i.e., any string at all, as long as it doesn't name a real file) and then see if you get an error message.  If you get no error, then clearly that code isn't being run.

Comment: `message` also sends the string to the `*Messages*` buffer.  Useful if there are several messages, and the later ones overwrite the earlier in the echo area.